# SSRS - Programmatically flag when a report is created as a snapshot

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to programmatically determine if a report is being run as a snapshot?

I have a suite of reports that need to behave differently when a snapshot is created than when run by the end user.

Differences include:

1. Tablix and column visibility
2. Multi-parameters (both available choices and defaults)
3. Expressions in textboxes in header
4. Expressions in tablix cells

I have been able to work around most of these issues but it is a series of kludges. Ideally I would like an `IsSnapshot()` function that I can use throughout the report.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use `IIf(User!UserID = "",True,False)` in expressions to flag scheduled snapshot (but not manually triggered ones).

Unfortunately SSRS realises that `User!UserID` is volatile and so won't let me use it if I also want to use Data Driven Subscriptions: ["You cannot create a data-driven subscription on a report that contains the User!UserID expression"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156012(v=sql.105).aspx)

In order to work round this I made my own public function in the report "Code" properties:

```sql
Public Function UserName()
  Try
   If IsDBNull(Report.User!UserID) Then Return ""
   If IsNothing(Report.User!UserID) Then Return ""
   Return Report.User!UserID
  Catch
   Return ""
  End Try
 End Function
```

My report therefore uses `IIf(Code.UserName() = "",True,False)` as a snapshot flag.

My main issue with this is that I am then using the absence of a username to work out if I should show all data (as I want to in my snapshot). This seems like a security flaw in the making.

I would much rather have an explicit Snapshot flag and not rely on some byproduct of the snapshotting process!